# How can I dynamically change the size of an agent's icon in a 3D Display in Repast Simphony?

Tags: java, eclipse, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I am trying to change the 3D model's size of an agent programmatically but it doesn't seem to be a way, any ideas?

I tried making the agent extend the DefaultStyle3D class but there only is a method to update the scaling factor, which by the way does not appear to have any effect on the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little more research I found that Repast lets you set a method of the agent as a scaling factor to allow the dynamic change of its value, as specified in the reference manual https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastReference/RepastReference.html#_displays section 11.7